# Hosting multiple static sites programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare, netlify

I want to host multiple static websites from a single app (a website builder). Every tutorial I see explains how to set up a git repo and their service will deploy an app from there.

Any time a user updates a page on their site, my worker (I will use next, so I'm talking a backend route deployed on ie Vercel) would create a new html file and create / replace the route that it is given.

Every page in every user-generated website should always be just a simple static html file.

On top of this, I would like to programmatically register domains like with Route53 or similar.

Where do I get started? Should I just get a Cloudflare account and start with their API docs? Or do I need to start understanding k8s for stuff like this?

Comment: Have a deep look at https://github.com/greenpau/caddy-git Seems to be right what you want.